# New to bitcoin or cryptocurriencies

Tags: transactions, e-wallet

First, to make sense to me. It sounds like I need a personal wallet first and then go to a place like coinbase to purchase bitcoin. Now what's the difference between bitcoin and cryptocurrencies? 
So if the above is right, I purchase bitcoin and the transfer to my wallet for safer keeping. If anyone can answer these questions that would be great.

Comment: Take a look above to answer your questions and more that you will have.  Good luck and welcome to the world of Crypto Currencies.